# iTextSharp - XFA fill date/time field

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms, pdf, itext

The workflow is like this:

1. we download a template form, prefill values which will be static, export a XML template
2. the XML is parsed with a .NET forms app, dynamic values are added
3. the resulting XML needs to be imported back into the PDF template

All goes well using the MergeXfaData method on iTextSharp, however for some reason, date/time fields are not being filled in (textfields and checkboxes work ok). Cannot figure out why. Searching through forums I discovered someone saying XFA only works for textfields. Why is this and how to work around?

Also as a next step I will need to attach an attachment to the PDF form. The attachments are also PDF but iTextSharp would not attach them. Have searched many forums but none of the mentioned methods works for me.

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Yuri, I just tried it with a date/time field and it worked perfectly. I create a simple PDF in Live Cycle with two fields, 1 text and 1 date/time, and two buttons, Submit and Print. The sample PDF is [here](http://chris.vendiadvertising.com/Stackoverflow/XFA-5637151/Input.pdf):

I filled out the form and got this for XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topmostSubform>
    <Text1>Chris</Text1>
    <DateTimeField1>2012-04-12</DateTimeField1>
</topmostSubform>
```

When I imported it into the PDF and viewed the PDF in Acrobat the date/time field was filled out. I'm using iTextSharp 5.0.5.0 with the following code:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim PDF_Input_File As String = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "Input.pdf")
        Dim PDF_Output_File As String = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "Export.pdf")

        ''//Create our reader
        Dim reader As New PdfReader(PDF_Input_File)
        ''//Create our file stream to output to
        Using FS As New System.IO.FileStream(PDF_Output_File, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
            ''//Create the stamper
            Dim stamper As New PdfStamper(reader, FS)

            ''//Just loading the XML raw instead of reading from disk, less files to attach to the post
            Dim Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><topmostSubform><Text1>Chris</Text1><DateTimeField1>2012-04-12</DateTimeField1></topmostSubform>")
            Using MS As New MemoryStream(Bytes)
                ''//Fill out the form
                stamper.AcroFields.Xfa.FillXfaForm(MS)
            End Using

            stamper.Close()
        End Using

        reader.Close()


        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Could you by chance advise me on how to add a digital signature (to am existing field of known name) and automatically submitting the form?

Comment: Also, is there a way to tell whether the form has been successfully submitted or not?

Comment: I've never worked with digital signatures in PDFs but this resource might help you: http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html

Comment: Finally a code sample that I could use and get to work perfectly the first try.  I've wasted far too much time trying to get this to work and yours is the first code sample that I have found that is simple, easy to read, and works perfectly.  Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks @Amy Patterson! I've learned to always show full code instead of hoping everyone else can piece things together. Also, a year later when I need to do this again I don't need to start from scratch, I can just copy, paste and modify.