# Load PDF to MemoryStream in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pdf, xfa

I'm using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444815/automate-adobe-pdf-form-import-export-data-functions) to read my XFA data to my vb.net application. However, I cannot figure out how to load the populatedPDFFrom to the application.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim filePath As String

        filePath = "d:\waiver_testing\test_pdf\rfrprg67.pdf"

        TextBox1.Text = Export(filePath)

    End Sub

Public Shared Function Export(populatedPDFForm As System.IO.Stream) As System.IO.MemoryStream

        '  Exports XFA data from a PDF File
        '  <param name="populatedPDFForm">a readable stream of the PDF with a populated form</param>
        '  <returns>A stream containing the exported XML form data</returns>

        Dim outputStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        Dim reader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(populatedPDFForm)
        Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings
        settings.Indent = True
        'settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = True

        Using writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputStream, settings)
            reader.AcroFields.Xfa.DatasetsNode.WriteTo(writer)
        End Using

        Return outputStream

    End Function
```

Error on line:
`textbox1.text = Export(filePath)`

Error: 
`Value type "String" cannot be converted to to "System.IO.Stream"`

Can someone please throw me a bone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a String to Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351126/convert-a-string-to-stream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can not assign a `MemoryStream` to a string. You need to convert it first. For example to read the stream as Ascii you can use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`.
Also, your `Export` function seems to take in a stream as a parameter and not a file path. To handle that write:

```
Using inStream As Stream = File.OpenRead(filePath)
  TextBox1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Export(inStream).ToArray())
End Using
```